# Why ts-morph cannot get the classes of a typescript project?

Tags: typescript, ts-morph

I use `ts-morph` to analyse the classes inheritance relationship of a project:

I download this opensource project[antv/x6](https://github.com/antvis/X6) for testing:

```
import { Project } from "ts-morph";

const project = new Project();

project.addDirectoryAtPath("/Users/john/github_repo/@antv/X6/packages/")

const classes = project.getSourceFiles().flatMap((sourceFile) =>
  sourceFile.getClasses()
);

const classNames = classes.map((classDecl) => ({
  name: classDecl.getName(),
  fileName: classDecl.getSourceFile().getFilePath(),
}));

console.log(classNames)  //  there log `[]`
```

why it get an empty array ?

---

**Edit-01**

I log the classes, it is empty array, but under the packages, it's the source code, it have thousands of classes.

```
const classes = project.getSourceFiles().flatMap((sourceFile) =>
  sourceFile.getClasses()
);
console.log("classes: ", classes)  // classes:  []
```

Comment: Have you console logged your `classes` variable? Does it have any data to map?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [ts-morph document](https://ts-morph.com/setup/adding-source-files)

you should use `addSourceFilesAtPaths`:

```
//project.addDirectoryAtPath("/Users/john/github_repo/@antv/X6/packages/")
project.addSourceFilesAtPaths("/Users/john/github_repo/@antv/X6/packages/**/*{.d.ts,.ts}");
```